# How to move element in CSS up so that elements underneath will follow?

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have a code in HTML:

```
<div class="up"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

For example I need to move `.up` element `200px` upwards like this:

```
.up {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}
```

But then I will have `200px` gap between it and lower divs. How can I stick lower `div`'s to `.up` element so when I move it, lower `div`'s will follow?

Comment: How do you move the `div`? Please add the CSS as well and explain your actual goal a little more.

Comment: You will need to have the elements inside a container, otherwise the elements won't follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to move upward you should first look at what is filling the space that you want to put it in.  There is probably another element filling that space.  Otherwise look to reduce the margin.

you can use `margin: -10px 0 0 0;`

or

```
margin-top: -10px
```

to do a margin of -10 pixels

[Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You could put everything you want to move up in a container div, and then move the entire container up:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

//

```
.container
{
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}
```

OR

```
.container
{
  margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the amount you are repositioning the div to `margin-bottom`:

```css
body {
  padding: 5rem;
}

div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
}

.up {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```