# Image floating two divs

Tags: html, css

I was trying to re-create this specific design in HTML/CSS .

I couldn't make the image float on top of the 2 divs .

[image: Result]

I will so grateful if someone could help me in the text design.

This is what I tried so far :

[image]

This code is for Blazor Component that's why there are variables

```css
.row-centered-elements {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  border-top-right-radius: 18px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.divider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.divider img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Graphik, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title {
  font-family: GraphikSemibold, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-centered-elements" <div class="card">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src=@imgBackCard1 alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <img src=@imgCircCard1 alt="Divider Image">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2 class="title">@Title1</h2>
    <p>@ParagraphCard1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src=@imgBackCard2 alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <img src=@imgCircCard2 alt="Divider Image">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2 class="title">@Title1</h2>
    <p>@ParagraphCard2</p>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using negative margin on the `divder`? Like `.divider { margin-top: -20px; z-index: 5;}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move element in CSS up so that elements underneath will follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243420/how-to-move-element-in-css-up-so-that-elements-underneath-will-follow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by adding a negative margin to the divider class and changing its position to relative

```css
.divider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -36px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```